# Json Patch in Asp.net core api with cosmos db

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, asp.net-core-webapi, json-patch, http-patch

Is it possible to use dotnet core api's HTTPPATCH / JSONPATCH with azure cosmos db?

Is there any sample?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-dotnet-application

Answer (score 1):

No, they are adding support for Patch API. You can track it here.https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/pull/1616